# Magmi. Conditional importing. Replace Value only if the destination is null

Tags: magento, magmi

How can I import some columns only if the destination column contains an empty value and has been never set.
The problem happens when I set the news_to_date. 
If in the value replacer I set something like this:

```
news_to_date:  {{date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+7 days'))}}
```

The destination on every magmi product update, is set to the current day + 7 days starting from today, but I need to keep the original value if the news_to_date attribute is already set.

Comment: Checking for pre-existing values on the fly is not supported by Magmi.  You'll have to write a custom Magmi plugin to do this.